# write compressed xml data to a memory stream using gzipstream

Tags: c#, memorystream, xmlwriter, gzipstream

I am trying to write a compressed xml data to a memory stream. Here is my test console app code:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var gstream = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress);

var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;

var writer = XmlWriter.Create(gstream, settings);
writer.WriteStartElement("x", "root", "123");
writer.WriteStartElement("item");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "x", null, "abc");
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndElement();            

Console.WriteLine("Data length: " + ms.ToArray().Length);

writer.Close();
gstream.Close();
ms.Close();    

Console.ReadLine();
```

And the output is:

```
Data length: 0
```

What am i doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must close the writer to flush the stream. Just change the code to:

```
writer.Close();
gstream.Close();
ms.Close();   

Console.WriteLine("Data length: " + ms.ToArray().Length);
```

and it should work.